# Is there a way to know when the DOM of a partial view is ready after it is inserted into the DOM of your web page?

Tags: dom, knockout.js, requirejs, ready

I'm writing an application using Knockout. I have subviews I'm inserting via jQuery's append() function. I'm using the text plugin for RequireJS to dynamically retrieve the HTML, then I'm using append() to attach it to an element in my web page:

```
$("#parentElement").append(theHTML);
```

After that, I need to bind "theHTML" to my ViewModel:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, $("#subViewElement")[0]);
```

It seems like the jQuery onDomReady() function is only used in the initial loading of the web page. Is there a way to make sure the DOM in "theHTML" is ready before calling "applyBindings" on it?

Comment: In my experience, the DOM is fully updated during the `append` call and immediately ready to be bound to.

Comment: Second that comment. As long as you call `applyBindings` after the `append` things should be ok. OP, you seem to imply that it doesn't work for you? Can you help us and show a repro where this doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, it works. Just paranoid that I'm only seeing it work as a result of just good response times and good luck. Wasn't sure if there was some tried and true way of programmatically knowing for sure.